Java.io, file won't open with bufferedreader and filereader when i compress it to a .jar, but when I execute the java file directly in VS it works
I'm learning how to use Java.io to manipulate and read files but I need the programs to be finished and ready to open with a .jar
As is, the code works fine, in the IDE it runs, but when I compress it and open the .jar the catch(FileNotFoundException e) error appears
package com.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class EjemploFichero01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("malaga1.csv"));
    
            String linea = "";
    
            while ((linea = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(linea);
           }
    
            bf.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("No se encuentra el fichero malaga.txt");
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("No se puede leer el fichero malaga.txt");
        }
    }

}


Tried to run the .jar file expecting the content of the file "malaga1.csv" to appear but i get the catch (FileNotFoundException e) error
I also run the -jar with
java -jar --enable-preview demo.jar

Resources (files included in a JAR), are not files on the file system, so you shouldn't try to open them as if they are files. You need to use the method getResourceAsStream from Class or ClassLoader. Or alternatively, if these are files on the filesystem, they are in a different location relative to the current working directory than you think they are. You need to specify an absolute path, or need some way to determine their actual location.
